# How to convert a data frame to matrix and multiply it by its transpose in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, transpose

I have a data frame of quantitative variables (columns) I'd like to convert to a matrix or array and then multiply it by its transpose.

Comment: Try `data.matrix(df) %*% t(data.matrix(df))`

Comment: `as.matrix(df) %*% t(as.matrix(df))`?

Comment: `crossprod(as.matrix(BOD))`

Comment: @mt1022, it'd be nice to encourage new users trying to build repuation to post questions even if they are simple/answered questions instead of rushing to down-vote them.

Comment: The links have explained why I (and also others) down-vote. If you have made any changes to imporve the original post, I will denifinitely retract the down-vote. If you show your efforts to sovlve it yourself, I may up-vote it even if it is anaswered to too simple. Although some very simple questions have very high votes, asking such questions never should be a strategy to get votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df<-data.frame(a=1:5,b=rep(1,5),c=5:1)
mat <- as.matrix(df)
```

and then

```
mat %*% t(mat)
```

or

```
t(mat) %*% mat
```